# Cleaner way to write inline c# in .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, inline-code

For reasons that are probably not worth mentioning in this post, I have decided to stop using ASP.NET controls and simply use regular HTML controls for my .aspx pages. As such, to dynamically generate HTML, I use c# inline to the .aspx to do what I need to do.

For example: this .aspx snippet shows how I am dynamically creating a <select> element where the <option> elements are driven by looping through a generic list of objects.

```
<select name="s">
<option value="-9999">Select an entity...</option>
<% foreach (MyEntity e in this.MyEntities)
 {%>
<option <% if (MyEntityInScope.ID == e.ID)
 { %>selected<%} %> value="<%= e.ID %>">
<%= e.Name%></option>
<%} %>
</select>
```

Functionality-wise, I prefer this method of creating HTML (I feel more in control of how the HTML is generated vs ASP controls). However, syntactically (and visually), I think it's cumbersome (and ugly).

Is there a "better" way (another syntax) to dynamically generate HTML w/out resorting to using ASP.NET controls?

Comment: Sounds as you want to use "ASP.NET MVC" instead..

Comment: Take a look at the new .Net MVC project type.  It sounds like it matches more with the way you are thinking.  http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: I watched Scott Guthrie's vid http://vimeo.com/7215798 on MVC. Although I felt slight motivation to take the time to learn/implement MVC, I couldn't help but wonder why I should learn a new paradigm/framework when all I really need to do is learn syntactical issues for creating HTML. To be honest, I'm still on the fence whether to dive into MVC or not. That being said, I am sure that I'm done with ASP.NET form controls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you put your logic into a method and call this method?

```
string GetEntityList()
{
// ...
}

<select name="s">
<option value="-9999">Select an entity...</option>
<%=  GetEntityList() %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is XML through XSLT. That is, your code assembles an XML document, loads a suitable XSLT transform and sends the result.

Comment: why does it sound bad? Whenever you need to change the presentation layer you then don't need to change the code, you just change the XSLT (and for the visual styling you change the CSS if you want to have clean XSLT/HTML). One can use a custom control on the server to do the XML to HTML conversion via XSLT, like this one: http://clipflair.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/Components/CustomXml/CustomXml.cs

Answer (score 2):

A utility method that returns an HTML string can help with that, similar to the HTML helpers in ASP.NET MVC.